# 'sudo gem install' or 'gem install' and gem locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

Running '`sudo gem list --local`' and '`gem list --local`' give me differing results. My gem path is set to my home folder and only contains the gems from '`gem list --local`'.

It's probably not good to have gems installed in different directories on my computer, so should I have the gem path set differently, and should I always use `sudo` when installing something?

```
my ~/.profile
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

~/.bash_profile is empty.

Comment: I think this is a valid question for those of us who have to use a gem that requires root privileges.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141584/rails-is-not-using-my-global-ruby-version. I use rbenv for managing Ruby versions and ran into an issue because I used `sudo gem install rails` instead of  `gem install rails`.

Comment: "I think this is a valid question for those of us who have to use a gem that requires root privileges." I think any gem that needs root privileges, either to be installed, or to run, is highly suspicious. Gems should be able to run in a sandbox and run with the user's permissions.

Comment: `sudo` is a loaded gun pointed toward your foot. Using it without understanding what it does and how it can affect your system is like pulling the trigger with your eyes closed. You might shoot a hole in your foot, you might not, but either way you don't want to run the risk unless you know how to undo the damage. Using `sudo` writes into the system-owned Ruby, which, on Mac OS, was installed by Apple for their own uses. We can piggyback on it, but changing the wrong thing can break their code. That's why we install from source or use something else to install where we can safely tweak it.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Contrary to all the other posts I suggest NOT using `sudo` when installing gems.

Instead I recommend you install **[RVM](https://rvm.io/)** and start a happy life with portable gem homes and different version of Ruby all living under one roof.

For the uninitiated, from [the documentation](http://rvm.io):

> RVM is a command line tool which allows us to easily install, manage and work with multiple ruby environments and sets of gems.

The reason why installing gems with `sudo` is worse than just `gem install` is because it installs the gems for *ALL USERS* as `root`.  This might be fine if you're the only person using the machine, but if you're not it can cause weirdness.

If you decide you want to blow away all your gems and start again it's much easier, and safer, to do so as a non-root user.

If you decide you want to use `RVM` then using `sudo` will cause all kinds of weirdness because each Ruby version you install through `RVM` has its own GEM_HOME.

Also, it's nice if you can make your development environment as close to your production environment as possible, and in production you'll most likely install gems as a non-root user.

Comment: +1 for the rvm suggest, but -1 for the confusing condemnation of the alternate possibility of just using sudo

Comment: Ok, but all your reasons boil down to "because RVM is so great" not because using sudo is especially harmful.  The only time you wouldn't want to is in the specific situation that you're on a shared computer.    If you want to recommend rvm just do that.  No need to resort to FUDD.

Comment: I try not spread FUD, and I tried to give non-RVM reasons, I apologise if it seems that way.

Comment: RVM is a good option. But you should try a better one, RBENV. It's less intrusive than RVM.

Comment: As somebody who do not know much about Ruby, I miss the the reasons behind every statement of this answer. Why I am supposed to use different versions of Ruby at the same time? Why it is a problem to instal a program for all users. It is the standard practice in *nix to install things as root, but run them as a restricted user. Why does this differ in the Ruby world? What kind of weirdness do you talk about? And so on.

Comment: @HontváriJózsefLevente it's hard to address all of your questions in a comment, but the short of it is that you want your development environment to be as close as possible to production. if you are working on two apps, one of which uses ruby 2.1 and the other which users 1.9 then you'll need to make sure your local environment is using the right version. that is what RVM or RBENV does for you. You would use it for the same reason you would use any sandbox environment, but the main benefit in this case is isolation. I hope this helps!

Comment: @jonii: As I understand it, the recommendation against sudo is valid for development machines. What about servers? Should we use sudo there?

Comment: @HontváriJózsefLevente it depends on your environment. i don't have any specific recommendations other than see what works best.

Comment: Note that broken or malicious gem may execute arbitrary commands. For example https://github.com/wmorgan/killergem attempts during installation to delete every file in root directory.

Comment: In practicality you'll rarely be hosting multiple apps with different ruby versions. RVM is overkill for production, so until you really need it, don't bother using it. I've been using RVM for years in production and removed it and now its one less thing I have to worry about. When you have docker containers its so easy to rebuild with a new ruby version if you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 163):

You can install gems in your local environment (without `sudo`) with

```
gem install --user-install <gemname>
```

I recommend that so you don't mess with your system-level configuration even if it's a single-user computer.

You can check where the gems go by looking at gempaths with `gem environment`. In my case it's "~/.gem/ruby/1.8".

If you need some binaries from local installs added to your path, you can add something to your bashrc like:

```
if which ruby >/dev/null && which gem >/dev/null; then
    PATH="$(ruby -r rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

(from http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install)

Comment: +1 for this option rather than the "Yet Another Configuration Tool" solutions above, RBENV / RVM.

Comment: I am creating a gem and according to manuals I have to do `rake install` and to fix the sudo isse, I had to patch manually the `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb` adding `--user-install` there. Can't find better solution, because looks like `rake install` doesn't accept additional parameters.

Comment: I am absolutely thrilled with that first command. I have been trying to install gems and have been having issues because I don't have sudo privileges. That command worked!!!!

Comment: `ruby -r rubygems -e 'puts Gem.dir'` and `ruby -r rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir'` print paths of global and user gems. `gem env home` and `gem env user_gemhome`(Ruby 3.2.0) do the same things.

Answer (score 42):

Better yet, put `--user-install` in your ~/.gemrc file so you don't have to type it every time

```
gem: --user-install
```

Answer (score 18):

In case you

- installed ruby gems with sudo
- want to install gems without sudo
- *don't want to install rvm/rbenv*

add the following to your `.bash_profile` :

```
export GEM_HOME=/Users/‹your_user›/.gem
export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Open a new tab in Terminal OR `source ~/.bash_profile` and you're good to go!

Comment: For someone not working with Ruby, Rails, Rake, and whatever else Ruby Devs use / want to use THIS solution is a lot easier than using rvm. I really don't care about having different ruby versions I just want to run some shell programs distributed as gems. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo gem install --no-user-install <gem-name>
```

will install your gem **globally**, i.e. it will be available to all user's contexts.

Comment: It can also overwrite a vendor installed gem, which that OS might expect to be set to a specific version. And that could break code that relies on it.

Comment: ...or it could install a gem that a vendor doesn't provide, and do so in a way that makes it available to all users on a system.  It's mildly aggravating that all the answers everywhere assume the reader is a dev v/s a sysadmin who actually _does_ want to make a specific version of a gem available to all users. :D

Answer (score 9):

Related (for bundler users), if you want a lighter alternative to RVM which will put everything in a user-specific well known directory, I recommend using:

```
bundle install --path $HOME/.gem
```

if you want to install gems to the same place that

```
gem install --user-install GEMNAME
```

will install them, `.gem/ruby/RUBYVERSION` in your homedir. (See the other comment on this question about `--user-install`.)

This will make the gems visible to `gem list`, uninstallable via `gem uninstall`, etc. without needing `sudo` access. Runnable scripts installed by gem or bundler can be put into your path by adding

```
$HOME/.gem/ruby/RUBYVERSION/bin
```

to your `$PATH`. `gem` itself tells you about this if it isn't set when you do `gem install --user-install`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to make bundler do this by default? (And if so, would it be a good idea?)

Answer (score 3):

You can install gems into a specific folder (example vendor/) in your Rails app using :

```
bundle install --path vendor
```

Comment: This. These days the only program that should need sudo to install software is your package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Ruby gems on a Mac is a common source of confusion and frustration. Unfortunately, most solutions are incomplete, outdated, and provide bad advice. I'm glad the accepted answer here says to NOT use `sudo`, which you should never need to do, especially if you don't understand what it does. While I used RVM years ago, I would recommend `chruby` in 2020.

Some of the other answers here provide alternative options for installing gems, but they don't mention the limitations of those solutions. What's missing is an explanation and comparison of the various options and why you might choose one over the other. I've attempted to cover most common scenarios
in my [definitive guide to installing Ruby gems on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/).