# Install ruby gem globally from github repository

Tags: ruby, command-line, github, rubygems

I want to install a ruby gem globally (`sudo gem install capybara-webkit`) but I want it to be installed from the master in its github repository.  I know this can be done using bundler but I want to do it from the command line because I'm coding mainly using pry.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

1. Download the source:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.git
   ```
2. Build the gem:

   ```
   cd capybara-webkit && gem build capybara-webkit.gemspec
   ```
3. Install it (the filename/version may vary):

   ```
   sudo gem install capybara-webkit-0.14.1.gem
   ```

Comment: I would leave the `sudo` off of step 3, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations) but otherwise, great answer! The one other thing to note is that the `.gemspec` file isn't always exactly the same as the name of the gem or the directory it's in, so just double check the filename before step 2.

Comment: I'm not sure of the effect of `sudo` by on Cygwin I used `gem install --no-user-install`, otherwise it installs into `~/.gem/ruby/$VER`. `--no-user-install` is a saver.