# Ruby gem fails to load

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've installed a gem from command line:

```
sudo gem install jalalidate
```

gem says it's installed:

```
$ gem list jalalidate
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jalalidate (0.3.2)
```

And it can be loaded:

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jalalidate"' # output is empty, (success?)
```

Though when I try to include this gem in a Rakefile, rake fails:

```
# Rakefile:
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "stringex"
require "jalalidate"

# Terminal:
$ rake new_post["title"]
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- jalalidate

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Note:

- I'm using octopress blogging system, and I'm trying to convert dates generated by `Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` to Jalali calender system, (`JalaliDate.new(Date.today).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`).
- I'm not familiar with Ruby

Update:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/soroush/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: for kicks, what's your `ls $GEM_PATH/gems` say

Comment: Do you run `rake` command with sudo too?

Comment: I don't have `$GEM_PATH` in environment

Comment: Does it work for you if you run the rake command under sudo?

Comment: @Psylone No. AFAIK it's not supposed to be run as sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Rakefile` has `require "bundler/setup"` before you try to require `jalalidate` which means you are using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) and so you have a `Gemfile`, which is restricting the gems (and versions) available.

In order to use the gem in your project, add the line

```
gem "jalalidate"
```

to the `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks :) Adding `gem "jalalidate"` to `gemfile` works perfectly. I think I'm have to learn a little bit of Ruby

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations) about why using sudo with gem commands is mostly a bad idea.

I recommend trying to install the gem without sudo: `gem install jalalidate`