# Rails is not using my global Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv

I want to use Rails with Ruby 2.1.0, but it's using Ruby 1.9.3 (the system's version).

I'm using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to manage my Ruby versions. My steps were something along the lines of:

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.0
$ rbenv global 2.1.0
$ sudo gem install rails -v 4.0.2
$ rbenv rehash
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.1.0 (set by /home/dennis/.rbenv/version)
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails new app && cd app
$ rails server
```

Rails is using is Ruby 1.9.3 (x86_64-linux), according to `localhost:3000/rails/info/properties`. A log message from `rails server` gives: `INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]`.

I think Rails is using the system version of Ruby because the versions match.

```
$ rbenv local system
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ rbenv local --unset  # Unset local Ruby version, go back to 2.1.0
```

Some things I've tried with no luck:

- setting the local and shell versions of Ruby to 2.1.0 with rbenv
- rehash rbenv shims (rbenv says to do this  after installing executables)
- made new Rails projects after switching to 2.1.0 just in case I made the projects while using 1.9.3
- putting `2.1.0` in a `.ruby-version` file in the root of my project (suggested by @Agis)
- restarting terminal session and starting a login bash shell (suggested by @Russel)
- specifying the desired Ruby version in the project's Gemfile (suggested by @rlecaro2)

FWIW, I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with the fish shell.

Comment: Check with `which rails` and `which ruby` that you're actually using the rbenv shims

Comment: `which rails` => `/usr/local/bin/rails`, 
`which ruby` => `/home/dennis/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: Did You used RVM for installation?

Comment: @Abhinay No, I don't even have RVM installed. I used [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) with [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) to build & install Ruby 2.1.0.

Comment: @Dennis Mate, sorry to say but If you really want to  Learn Rails with " no issues with installation ".Simply go with rvm otherwise these things will occur frequently. Even http://stackoverflow.com/users/497756/mpapis has suggested the same..Enjoy !!.If you say then I'll post all the steps below for you here.

Comment: With rvm you can handle more than 2 or 3 versions of ruby at the same time.

Comment: @Dennis On my installation, the rails use is `~/.rbenv/shims/rails`. Check the .rbenv/shims directory is first in PATH `echo $PATH`

Comment: @Baldrick Yes, `~/.rbenv/shims` is the first path in my $PATH.

Comment: @Abhinay I'll give RVM a try if I can't resolve this issue with rbenv.

Comment: @Dennis So it means `~/.rbenv/shims/rails` is missing. `gem` should also be a shims, and `rbenv rehash` should have created the rails shim after installing the rails gem. Something went wrong, I don't know what. Sorry.

Comment: @Baldrick thanks for the help! That I'm missing a path is definitely progress. I tried `rbenv rehash` again followed by `which -a rails` but it still only shows `/usr/local/bin/rails`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't tell how you installed `rbenv`, but I think it is per-user installation (which is default). In this case you should install gems without using `sudo`. When you did `sudo gem install rails`, it was installed in system ruby, not rbenv's selected one.

Solution - install rails without sudo:

```
rbenv global 2.1.0
gem install rails
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: I installed rbenv by cloning the repo to `~/.rbenv`, prepending `~/.rbenv/bin` to my $PATH, and following the instructions from `rbenv init` which involved adding a line to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` so that rbenv loads automatically. I then cloned the ruby-build repo to `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build` and prepended `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin` to my $PATH.

Comment: Yes, this is per-user (default) installation. Try installing rails without `sudo` as I suggested.

Comment: I installed Rails as suggested (and verified Ruby version first), but Rails is still showing the old version. Previous to installing Rails with `gem install rails`, the command `gem which rails` would return "ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library rails", but now it returns "/home/dennis/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails.rb". Perhaps I first need to uninstall the Rails gem that I installed with sudo, going to try `sudo gem uninstall rails` next.

Comment: Solved! Your solution worked, but I had to run `rbenv rehash` in addition. I didn't have to uninstall Rails like I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Also, don't forget to call `rbenv rehash`

Comment: I was running into pretty much the same problem trying to get jekyll working. The keys were installing jekyll again so that it would get installed in the ~/.rbenv directory and then running rbenv rehash so I could run the jekyll commands.  And...the site is running.  Woohoo!

Answer (score 9):

Sounds silly, but did you restart terminal session?

Otherwise try and type

```
 /bin/bash --login
```

Comment: And then rerun ruby -v to check

Comment: Just tried restarting the terminal and created a new Rails project, but still uses the older Ruby version. Trying `/bin/bash --login` also did not work, `ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]` but `rails server` still says `ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux`.

Comment: So logging into your bash profile did seem to work... If I'm nost mistaken, your previous rails version was 1.9.3 and now is reading 2.1. Unless you have a ruby version specified in your rails project, if you ran 'rails s' with your updated ruby version, it should have started with that version. Is your server detached? Did you run it with -d when you started? Did you ever restart it?

Comment: Correct, the default Ruby version on Ubuntu 13.10 is 1.9.3 and I installed 2.1.0 with rbenv and ruby-build. I didn't specify a specific Ruby version in my Rails project, it that specified somewhere by default? What does it mean for my server to be detached? (I'm running the Rails server locally on my development machine.) I did not run Rails with the `-d` option. I tried restarting the server several times by killing it with `ctrl+c` and then rerunning `rails server`.

Comment: gotcha. I should have simplified and asked if you had restarted the rails server. running 'rails s -d' Will run the the server detached. So it will launch and run without being attached to the terminal session basically

Comment: if you do that you will have to find the pid and kill it. So running like 'pgrep -l -f thin' would find a thin server, which is what I typically use. But now I'm getting way off topic. So if I think of anything I shall return

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Someone suggested that I'm missing a path in my $PATH (see comments below question), so I'm going to look into that some more.

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a `.ruby-version` file in the root of your project with the following contents:

```
2.1.0
```

Comment: I created `~/app/.ruby-version` with the contents `2.1.0` then did `rails server` but it still shows Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: What if you open irb? Still 19.3?

Comment: Running irb in my project directory, `RUBY_VERSION` gives `2.1.0`.

Comment: The root folder fo your app isn't the app folder. You could also try specifying the ruby version in the gemfile: `ruby "2.1.0"` (restart terminal).

Comment: @rlecaro2 What is the root folder to my Rails app? My home directory? I tried specifying the Ruby version in the app's Gemfile. When I run `rails server` I get the error message "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0". I assume Rails is using `/usr/bin/ruby` (1.9.3) instead of `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby` (2.1.0).