# Why does rails server Welcome Aboard site report a different ruby version to rbenv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv, multiple-versions

I am using rbenv on Debian. Debian came pre-installed with ruby 1.9.3. I installed rbenv and used it to install ruby 2.1.2. I then used `rails new` to make a fresh rails application.

`rbenv versions`

gives

```
system
* 2.1.2 (set by /home/jordanmorris/code/TestRail/.ruby-version)
```

`rbenv global` gives `2.1.2`
`rbenv local` (in the new application folder) gives `2.1.2`
`ruby -v` gives `2.1.2`
`which ruby` gives `/home/jordanmorris/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

However, when I use `rails server` (node.js), view the 'Welcome aboard site' and click "About your application’s environment", it reports:
`Ruby version`  `1.9.3-p484 (x86_64-linux)`

**Why is this not displaying the version set with rbenv as expected, and is this a cause for concern?**

I only have one version of rails installed, afaik, and it reports correctly (4.1.4).

Comment: in your application folder if you type `which ruby` do you get the rbenv ruby or the system ruby?

Comment: @Anthony `which ruby` gives `/home/jordanmorris/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: For testing, can you add the line `ruby '2.1.2'` to your Gemfile, run `rails server`, and check the application's environment again?

Comment: Is `~/.rbenv/shims` the [first directory in your path](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#understanding-path)?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' The shims path is at the start of my $PATH. Interesting - when I add `ruby'2.1.2'` to my Gemfile, `rails server` fails with `Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2`

Comment: I created another fresh application with `rails new`, and I found this file in a file called `rails` in `[application_folder]/bin/`. It contains the following:  

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1`  
`begin`  
`load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)`  
`rescue LoadError`  
`end`  
`APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)`  
`require_relative '../config/boot'`  
`require 'rails/commands'`

Comment: Check all the sources at ["Choosing the Ruby version"](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version). What do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70367/discussion-between-jordan-morris-and-mike-sherrill-cat-recall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21142991/970673) answer helped me.

The problem was that I installed rails using `sudo`.

rbenv operates on a per-user basis. So, `rbenv install` installed ruby 2.1.2 for jordanmorris, whereas `sudo gem install rails` installed rails using the only version of ruby/gem installed for root (1.9.3).

Afterwards, every time I ran `rbenv` or `ruby`, they used the expected rails version determined by rbenv, but every time I ran `rails new` or `rails server`, it would use the rails installed on top of ruby 1.9.3, that being the only instance of rails existing.

I followed these steps to fix it:

1. Uninstall rails and it's dependencies (just because I like to keep a tidy house).
2. Install rails and it's dependencies WITHOUT using `sudo`.
3. Run `rbenv rehash`.
4. Regenerate a new application (`rails new`).

The correct version now displays in the Welcome aboard -> About your application’s environment page.

Also note, the `rails new` command will create an application which uses spring. Consider installing [rbenv-binstubs](https://github.com/ianheggie/rbenv-binstubs) to avoid stub clashes with rbenv.