# Jekyll serve didn't work: It looks like you don't have pygments or one of its dependencies installed

Tags: jekyll, pygments

```
Configuration file: /Users/andrechristoga/Documents/type-theme/_config.yml
       Deprecation: You appear to have pagination turned on, but you haven't included the `jekyll-paginate` gem. Ensure you have `gems: [jekyll-paginate]` in your configuration file.
            Source: /Users/andrechristoga/Documents/type-theme
       Destination: /Users/andrechristoga/Documents/type-theme/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have pygments or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- pygments' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
  Liquid Exception: pygments in /Users/andrechristoga/Documents/type-theme/_posts/2014-11-28-markdown-and-html.md
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    pygments
```

These are the message when I type `jekyll serve`.

Comment: install pygments: `gem install pygments.rb`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I had the same issue but fixed it installing pygments gem.

```
gem install pygments.rb
```

And adding it to my Gemfile.

```
gem 'pygments.rb'
```

Comment: In my jekyll template I didn't have a `Gemfile`

Answer (score -2):

If you use the command `sudo gem install pygments.rb` or `gem install pygments.rb`, it may not works

So you can try root:

```
su root
gem install pygments.rb
```

This fix my problem.

Comment: it is not recommended to use root for gem see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations

Answer (score -2):

if you are a windows user, you could run CLI as administrator. This would help.