# Getting Pygments dependency error when trying to compile Jekyll site

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rbenv, pygments, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm beginning to set up a Jekyll site and I've installed everything and copied the contents of [this theme](http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/jekyll-uno/) into the site's directory. I've installed Pygments via the `gem install pygments.rb` command and it seemed to install fine. But I'm still getting the error from my screenshot below when trying `jekyll serve` . I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439019/jekyll-serve-didnt-work-it-looks-like-you-dont-have-pygments-or-one-of-its-dep) and tried the commands in the given answer, installing pygments worked fine, but when I tried `gem 'pygments.rb'` I got the error in the first line of the screenshot "Unknown command pygments.rb".

I'm running this command in the directory with my gemfile, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

[image]

I'm not really sure what else I can try. I've installed pygments but I still get the error that it is not installed. I am using rbenv to manage my Ruby versions, I have the global ruby version set to 2.0.0-p247. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Edit: So I followed the theme's install guide, but I'm getting the same error except for Kramdown:

Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Markdown encountered an error while converting '_posts/2016-01-08-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown':
                    Missing dependency: kramdown
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Missing dependency: kramdown

Comment: shot into the dark but do you have python installed? http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting

Comment: @matrixanomaly I actually wasn't sure if I did or not when I saw this, so I ran `brew install Python` and let it do its thing. Still getting the same error though, so I guess that wasn't the problem :( Thanks though

Comment: hmm the only other thing I can think of is to try setting your ruby version again with rbenv, then doing `gem install pygments.rb` to avoid the chance of it installing to the global gem collection. or just clear your local ruby env and start over, I ran into many weird errors like these and clearing it all and starting over seemed to fix the problem. (Alternatively, remove the syntax highlighting part and use something like `rouge`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't use a snapshot of the screen to display errors, code, status messages, or anything else we'd need to help answer your question. We can't copy/paste that information into a search box to look for additional information when trying to help, nor can search engines index that information to help others find a solution to similar questions. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]".

Comment: @theTinMan Yeah sorry, I thought about that before I posted it. I've been copy & pasting that error into google all day and haven't found an answer. I've recreated the Jekyll page directory and tried some other stuff. Now I'm essentially getting the same error but with Kramdown as my missing dependency, so I'm working through that issue now.

Comment: You can run a `jekyll --trace` command and see what results are brought to you. Installing Jekyll is a little tricky, but after everything's fine you'll love it. The other thing is, Jekyll has recently released a new version, and I've read there are less dependencies, and they changed from pygments to rouge as default highlighter. Anyway, before using any template, make sure Jekyll is working by building a new project with the command `jekyll new mysite` where `mysite` is the name if your project - pick whatever name you want. After that, if Jekyll builds, you can go on and work on your theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you read theme's [install steps](https://github.com/joshgerdes/jekyll-uno/blob/master/README.md#start-in-4-steps), your not supposed to battle with any pygments install.

Here are two working ways for a Jekyll install :

- http://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/
- https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#installing-jekyll

Comment: I tried the theme's install steps, but I'm still getting the same error, except for Kramdown. I updated my post with the error.

Comment: Did follow this installations steps : https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#installing-jekyll ? Once it's done you start your site with `bundle exec jekyll serve`.