# How to stop sudo installing gems. The ultimate solution

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, rvm, rbenv

So I've read every post on how to stop sudo installing gems and there's literally 100's of different answers and one still hasn't struck as gold yet. Can someone, once and for all, offer the most simple and concise manner in which to edit and update your bash profile to rewrite permissions and stop sudo installing gems?

Below is just an example to show you what I get every time. For the past few weeks, I've just been doing everything and I know this is putting a band-aid over the problem.

```
LMagnotti$ gem install nokogiri

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/.autotest
```

Comment: to stop installing ruby gems from sudo just use rvm/rbenv apps, they allow to mount system rubyes

Comment: Do you mean: "how to install gems without need for `sudo`?"

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18294746/1566267): `gem install --user-install <gemname>`. Or use `RBENV`/`RVM`

Comment: A possible conflating problem is using `sudo` when not required can make it required later on (because you end up with files/folders owned by root when they shouldn't be)

Comment: I'm not completely sure that your problem is exactly the same as in the question I just linked to as a duplicate, but I'm pretty sure the solution is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to stop installing ruby gems from sudo just use [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) or [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) apps, they allow to mount system rubies, otherwise all the gems will be installed to system folder since `rubygem` app is also installed to system. That is proper way to use gems for each project, but also you can specify in [**~/.gemrc**](https://blogs.oracle.com/mandy/entry/rubygems_etc_gemrc) another folder in your home or in **var/** folder:

```
gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
gemhome: /var/ruby/1.8/gem_home
gempath:
 - /usr/ruby/1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Comment: But I have rvm installed? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall ruby with rbenv. It store gems and ruby inside your users home directory, so when you'll install gems no need for sudo