# Error with Bundle Install (Linux)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Upon trying to start a new Rails App on Linux, I am receiving this error:

I am a newbie to this software. Please help!

Thanks :)

[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUVVi.png)

UPDATE: I ran 'sudo gem install bundler', and it worked but now received this error!

'/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)'

[My new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hIrX.png)

Comment: If you are new, I recommend you find a good guide for RVM or rbenv. Those two will allow you to install Ruby in the user space, so you don't/shouldn't have to use sudo at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont have bundler gem installed.

Try:

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked! I now received a new error, link above :)

Comment: @Benjamints, try this: `gem install rails`, and after that run `bundle`

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is missing.

Try the below commands.

```
[sudo] gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Comment: Thank you, but it has now given me a new error, link above :)

Answer (score 0):

Try stop using sudo in your commands. According to your new capture, you are using sudo with `gem install bundler`, and maybe that is conflicting with your configuration.

Take this link for reference for `sudo` usage with `gem`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119413/4870465