# Byebug error while installing

Tags: ruby

I am having problems installing `byebug`:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir -
/Users/CTO/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/byebug-5.0.0
An error occurred while installing byebug (5.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install byebug -v '5.0.0' succeeds before bundling.
```

I ran the recommended install command and got this:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/CTO/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/byebug-5.0.0
```

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try with `sudo gem install byebug -v 5.0.0`?

Comment: You may want to consider not using `sudo`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations) post which covers why using `sudo` is undesirable and some workable alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a permission denied error when trying to install a gem in your local copy of `rbenv`, so I'm guessing there are some files in that directory that aren't owned by your user.

To verify this, you could run the following command to identify any files that aren't owned by your user (assuming your username is `CTO`):

```
find ~/.rbenv \! -user CTO
```

If that is indeed the problem, you can run the following to fix it:

```
sudo chown -R CTO ~/.rbenv
```