# ruby- packetgen installation gives gem install error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install packetgen, a library for crafting and manipulating network packets. I followed all the instructions, and installed all the necessary libraries. However, when I ran `sudo gem install packetgen`
to install it on my Linux machine it raised an error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing packetgen:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.4/ext/pcaprub_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20181009-29130-us1azm.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.4                  for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0   /pcaprub-0.12.4/gem_make.out [here][1]
```

I ran the command as sudo, but got the same error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? The link to installation instructions is [here.](https://github.com/sdaubert/packetgen/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sudo gem install` but rather it is highly recommended that you use a ruby version manager, probably RVM, for more reasons why, see ['sudo gem install' or 'gem install' and gem locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations)

Based on your error it looks like you're trying to use your system ruby which will likely have permission and/or library dependency issues.  These are easily solved by using a version manager which has many advantages including the ability to use different ruby versions on the same system and not having to use `sudo` or root level installs of gems.

You can install [RVM from here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

Instructions on gem link you posted do say gem depends on `sudo apt install libpcap-dev` which is a system lib your gem needs to build.  I assume you did that step already right?