# cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

on a mac os 10.12.6 after i try **sudo gem install rake**  or

i get this error message:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

The is error throws any gem install
Ruby version is 2.0.0, Ive tried updating ruby with homebrew but whni try installing home brew i get the same error.

Cant seem to edit /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1395

Comment: It is widely accepted amongst ruby community not to `sudo gem install`  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations#2119413

Comment: Do you actually have a working install of homebrew?

Comment: no I do not have a working homebrew, Im totally a nube thanks for your help.

Comment: Install apple dev tools https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

then past output of `printenv`

Comment: sorry I dont understand, that page has many options to download. if i run **printenv** in terminal then it give me a big print out stuff. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1.dmg

Comment: also you were supposed to post the output of that command in your question so we can see what's going on.

Comment: ok I've added the output

Comment: ok remove printenv data from the post now.

Comment: I found this happening in Docker (building ruby from source) with rubygems 3.0.0 but not with 2.7.4.

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly related to issue [#2535](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2535) in rubygems fixed in [release 3.0.1](https://blog.rubygems.org/2018/12/23/3.0.1-released.html).

Try `gem update --system`

Answer (score 1):

All suggested solutions didn't fully work for me, although `gem update --system` seems to be a good idea, because it updates ruby. BUT: On my Mac, the system version didn't step back after the update, although `ruby -v` gave the correct new version. The described error remained for me, e.g. while using homebrew with `brew update`:

```
$ brew update
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

The only thing that helped me was the following [as described here](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/trouble-installing-homebrew-broken-ruby/3792/19):

```
sudo rm -f '/usr/local/bin/update_rubygems'
sudo rm -rf '/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0'
```

Hope to help some folks (I'am on MacOS 10.14.2).

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have problems using system ruby or messing with it's gems. You are far better off to use a ruby version manager where you may have different versions of ruby per project.  I highly recommend RVM.

[See here for how to install](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

Did you also try to run `gem install bundler`?

Post output of these commands if they don't give you an error

```
ruby -v
which ruby
gem env
```

Comment: Ive already tried using rvm but i get an error for that as well when I run **rvm install 2.6** saying it can't update homebrew and it failed to install the version of ruby                          Requirements installation failed with status: 255.

Comment: ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Comment: gem env
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

Comment: @TrimTrimm please post that as code in your question, hard to read this way