# unable to run gems using custom Ruby version on macOS Mojave

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I get error when trying to run any gem installed using ruby from `brew install ruby`

Here is slather example but this is same for any gem I tried (Jekyll, CocoaPods, Nokogiri etc.)

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem slather (>= 0.a) with executable slather (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:252:in `bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/slather:22:in `<main>'
```

gem is installed properly but for unknown reason ruby tries to use paths for system version.

I have read to not use `rvm` and `rbenv` and only brew version but this also do not work as above

ruby -v: `ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]`
gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/[user]/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/[user]/.fastlane/bin
     - /Users/[user]/.fastlane/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

any help appreciated

Comment: "I have read to not use rvm and rbenv and only brew version" Why?
Can you provide a link? `rbenv` usually works fine for me.

Comment: I had issues with using rbenv and rvm on unpriviledged user. Gems unaccessible or unable to install them because of lack of write permissions.

Comment: My recommendation for OSX, and my experience, is that [RVM](https://rvm.io/) will give us the better experience by far. You won't have any gems install issues as it all happens on your `$HOME` context. For example: _/Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/statsd-ruby-1.4.0/lib/statsd-ruby.rb_ location is perfectly safe and it works trouble free.

Comment: so I will need $HOME duplicates for my user and for Jenkins user? @RuiMarques

Comment: @PawełMadej you can install global gems or user level gems but I recommend to use simply RVM or rbenv, I favour the fist. Installing RVM is so easy to use.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations. I'm not agains using `sudo` but is something I would avoid.

If you need the Jenkins user on your OSX I would reconsider the way you're trying to use Jenkins and run it via Docker instead. I need to better understand what you're trying todo.

Comment: I use Jenkins as my local CI for testing iOS apps I develop, so I need macOS specific packages like xcodebuild etc so I installed Jenkins on bare macOS and it created for itself Jenkins user. I will try to use RVM on this user and write if it works